# getting more than one cllient socket connection to one server, Android

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I have two android tablets.  they are using sockets to connect over wifi.  I was able to get one client to connect and  send messages to the server.   How can I get a second client to connect to the server?

the ultimate goal is to get 2 or 3 android tablets running the client app to connect and send messages to the server Android Device at the same time.

some sample code from the app for the server android tablet

```
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction("com.example.test.state");
                            intent.putExtra("serverStatus","Connected");
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        //    Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                            receivedCommand = line;

                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction("com.example.test.diceRolled");
                            intent.putExtra("receivedLine", line.trim());
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the I/O for each accepted socket into a separate thread.